# Ошибка NameError: free variable 'li' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python

пытаюсь написать функцию с помощью генераторов списков для удаления дубликатов во входящем списке.

вместо результата выскакивает ошибка

```
NameError: free variable 'li' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

```py
def del_dublicates(arr):
    li=[x for x in arr if x not in li]
    return li
    
    print(del_dublicates([5,9,102,5,6,78,9]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас переменная `li` будет инициализирована только после завершения формирования списка через цикл, а вы уже обращаетесь к ней в цикле, когда переменная еще не существует - поэтому и ошибка

можно модернизировать и работать с проверкой по старому списку формируя новый:

```
def del_dublicates(arr):
    li=[x for i, x in enumerate(arr) if arr[:i].count(x) == 0]
    return li
```

ну или вашим способом делайте в лоб тогда:

```
def del_dublicates(arr):
    li = []
    for x in arr:
        if x not in li:
            li.append(x)
    return li
```

Answer (score 0):

Если порядок не важен, то просто `li = set(arr)`.